# huge and weird values after applying some calculations

Tags: python, excel, pandas, format

The values I got for some columns are just too huge other are in day/month format (see excel picture) and I was wondering why. Any help would be appreciated.

here you can see the excel İmage 
[image: excel output]

and the pandas İmage 
[image: pandas output]

Here is my code and the file is [here](https://gofile.io/?c=Zi4UMn)

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the file
data = pd.read_csv('/your_location/for_test.csv', sep = ';')

# Set the index
data = data.set_index('Date_Time') 

# Drop the duplicated rows
data = data.drop_duplicates(keep = "first")


# Create new columns using Addition and Multiplication
data['a1'] = data['x1'] * data['y1']
data['a2'] = data['x2'] * data['y2']
data['a3'] = data['x3'] * data['y3']

data['b1'] = data['x1'] * data['z1']
data['b2'] = data['x2'] * data['z2']
data['b3'] = data['x3'] * data['z3']

data['A'] = (data['a1'] + data['a2'] + data['a3']) * 0.01 
data['B'] = (data['b1'] + data['b2'] + data['b3']) * 0.01 
data['A+B'] = data['A'] + data['B'] 

# Final dataframe
data = data[['A+B', 'A']]

save_data = data.to_csv('/your_location/output.csv', sep = ';')

data
```

Comment: It looks as if, in just those cells, you are using the `dot` as a digit separator instead of a decimal separator, and multiplying the correct result by **10^13**. Very weird.

Comment: Changing the ```dot``` doesn't help and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong!